# Query to distribute cost as per number of account

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Part and Recv_Acct is common (Join Key) col in both Tables(A,B). Need query where Table B records should be tied to A.Send_Acc turnwise. Check the final output screenshot attached

**Table A**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [part] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Recv_acct] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Send_acct] [nvarchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT INTO a([id],[part],[Recv_acct],[Send_acct])
VALUES(1,'QR1','6722','307131')
,(2,'QR1','6722','22965')
,(3,'QR2','6700','12345')
,(4,'QR2','6700','54321')
Go

**Table B**
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[b](
    [Recv_acct] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [customer] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [invoice_number] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [PART] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [COST] [decimal](38, 6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO b([Recv_acct],[customer],[invoice_number],[PART],[COST])
VALUES('6722','ABC','3310','QR1','10500.00')
,('6722','ABC','5969','QR1','22400.00')
,('6722','ABC','5974','QR1','2100.00')
,('6722','ABC','8469','QR1','20300.00')
,('6722','ABC','8470','QR1','2100.00')
,('6700','DEF','5974','QR2','100.00')
,('6700','DEF','8469','QR2','2300.00')
,('6700','DEF','8470','QR2','2000.00')
```

**Final Output screenshot is available** [Final_Output_last_Col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uEra.png)

Comment: can you provide some logic to your query so we can create the required answer

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
SELECT b.* 
  , a.Send_acct
FROM table_b AS b
LEFT JOIN table_a AS a
ON b.PART = a.part
 AND b.Recv_acct = a.Recv_acct
```

Comment: I wish its that simple. Kindly check the screenshot attached for the final output. However, many thanks for quick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As no logic is mentioned for the derivation of expected result, so assuming that data needs to be sorted on column `invoice_number`, you can use `row_number()` along with `%(mod)` as below to get the result close to yours.

```
SELECT
  PART,
  Recv_acct,
  customer_Name,
  invoice_number,
  Cost,
  Send_Acct
FROM (SELECT
  t2.PART,
  t2.Recv_acct,
  t2.customer_Name,
  t2.invoice_number,
  t2.Cost,
  t1.Send_Acct,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.invoice_number ASC) AS rn
FROM tableB t2
JOIN tableA t1
  ON t2.part = t1.part
  AND t1.recv_acct = t1.recv_acct) t
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
ORDER BY part, invoice_number;
```

**Result:**

```
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| PART | Recv_acct | customer_Name | invoice_number |   Cost   | Send_Acct |
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3310 | 10500,00 |    307131 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3311 | 22400,00 |     22965 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3312 | 2100,00  |    307131 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3313 | 20300,00 |     22965 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3314 | 3100,00  |    307131 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2233 | 400,00   |     12345 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2244 | 4000,00  |     54321 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2333 | 500,00   |     54321 |
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DPV15959)**

---

To get the exact result mentioned in expected output, you need to sort `QR1` data ascending and `QR2` descending in separate queries and `union` afterward as below.

```
SELECT
  PART,
  Recv_acct,
  customer_Name,
  invoice_number,
  Cost,
  Send_Acct
FROM (SELECT
  t2.PART,
  t2.Recv_acct,
  t2.customer_Name,
  t2.invoice_number,
  t2.Cost,
  t1.Send_Acct,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.invoice_number ASC) AS rn
FROM tableB t2
JOIN tableA t1
  ON t2.part = t1.part
  AND t1.recv_acct = t1.recv_acct
WHERE t2.part = 'QR1') t
WHERE rn % 2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  PART,
  Recv_acct,
  customer_Name,
  invoice_number,
  Cost,
  Send_Acct
FROM (SELECT
  t2.PART,
  t2.Recv_acct,
  t2.customer_Name,
  t2.invoice_number,
  t2.Cost,
  t1.Send_Acct,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.invoice_number DESC) AS rn
FROM tableB t2
JOIN tableA t1
  ON t2.part = t1.part
  AND t1.recv_acct = t1.recv_acct
WHERE t2.part = 'QR2') t
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
ORDER BY part, recv_acct;
```

**Result:**

```
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| PART | Recv_acct | customer_Name | invoice_number |   Cost   | Send_Acct |
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3310 | 10500,00 |    307131 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3311 | 22400,00 |     22965 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3312 | 2100,00  |    307131 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3313 | 20300,00 |     22965 |
| QR1  |      6722 | ABC           |           3314 | 3100,00  |    307131 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2333 | 500,00   |     12345 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2244 | 4000,00  |     12345 |
| QR2  |      6700 | DEF           |           2233 | 400,00   |     54321 |
+------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UHAS38364)**

Comment: @user3516970: Kindly read [**Upvoting and Accepting Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :-)